# Javascript decodeURIComponent() with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I'm encoding URL's using javascript's [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function when a form is submitted:

```
  <form name="form" action="actions.php" method="post">

      <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="http://">

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function encodeLinks(){
            var e = document.getElementById('url')
            e.value = encodeURIComponent(e.value);        
        }  

      </script>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="encodeLinks()">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

What is the most efficient way to get that data back into javascript on the actions page in order to decode it and then use it in a mysql query?

Comment: *urldecode* is it this what u looking?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? When you submit a form, the inputs are encoded automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pointless to do this. The browser will automatically encode the data you are sending, and the server will automatically decode it. Everything is transparent, so you do not need to worry about it at all.